# Facebook Post Open Graph Story Error

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm receiving 400 Bad Requests error after calling post open graph. (Sometimes is error code 500 depends on how I modify the graph api call)

I never get it work before so I'm not sure whether my codes are correct or not.

Here's my codes:

```
FB.API("me/fb_unitytestapp:discover?fish=http://www.myapp.com", "POST", completionHandler);

1. fb_unitytestapp is my Facebook app namespace
2. discover is action
3. fish is object
```

The result I want is something like this
"Johnson discovered a Golden Fish in My Test App."

"Golden Fish" is an object and I want it to link to my app page. 
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
FB.API(
  "/me/fb_unitytestapp:discover",
  "POST",
  {
    "fish": "http:\/\/www.myapp.com"
  },
  completionHandler);
```

Comment: Hmm what if I just want to use back existing objects (without creating my own), then I want the output result to be something like this
"Johnson discovered Golden Fish in My Test App"